# Why is the Node.js javascript function res.write(data) outputting numbers when I log it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm using Node.js on my Raspberry Pi to read a local file 'test.html' and when I log the output it looks like it's hex and not the html.  Why is this?  Also, I understand fs.readFile is for local files only.  What would I use to read a URI like, 'myzone.example.com/test.html' ? (Thanks in advance for any assistance.)

```
function handler (req, res) { //create server
  fs.readFile('../Public/test.html', function(err, data) { //read file index.html in public folder
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //display 404 on error
      console.log(err);
      return res.end("404 Not Found at Arcade.");
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
    res.write(data); 
    console.log("Page Data: ", data);
    return res.end();
  });
}
```

Console.log output:

Page Data:  <Buffer 3c 21 64 6f 63 74 79 70 65 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 4d 79 20 48 54 4d 4c 20 50 61 67 65 3c ... 69 more bytes>

Comment: Are you not getting the correct output on your browser though?

Comment: ```res.write(data.toString('utf8'));``` should solve your problem. If you do not pass encoding argument in `fs.readFile`, raw buffer is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Because that’s how `fs.readFile` works.

From https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback:

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

So this is what you’re getting: the raw buffer contents.

If you want the contents as say, UTF-8, then you’ll need to specify that encoding when using `fs.readFile`:

```js
fs.readFile('../Public/test.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  //
});
```

Comment: I thought I was specifying HTML with   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); No?

Comment: That’s nothing to do with _reading_ the original file, though.

Comment: If I replace fs.readfile with https.request('myzone.example.com/test.html'), I'm getting HTML back.  So would I need to covert that back to hex and return it to replace the functionality of fs.readfile with https.request?

Comment: If you are just printing out on `console.log` to test it out just use [`buf.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end). If you want to send the data as it is you shouldn't try encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a HTTP request. This can easily be done with the package [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// get the HTML
async function run() {
    const res = await fetch("http://myzone.example.com/test.html");
    console.log(await res.text()); // res.text() gets the response body as text/HTML
}
setImmediate(run);
```

Comment: He's handling a request, not making one. Why does he need `fetch`?

Comment: At the end of his question he says "What would I use to read a URI like, 'myzone.example.com/test.html' ?", so i answered that.